# php export to csv user/browser download

Tags: php, csv, export

After much googling and tinkering around a bit i managed to export the table to .csv file but now i'd like to initiate the download via the browser instead of automatically storing in a folder.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'pass';
$db = 'test';

 $db = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);

mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");

$filename = 'uploads/'.strtotime('now').'.csv';

$fp = fopen($filename,"w");

$query = "SELECT id,product,status,created,summary FROM product_table";

$result =  mysqli_query($db,$query) or die( "My query ($query) generated an error: ".mysql_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value){
    $seperator.= $comma. ''.str_replace('','""',$name);
    $comma=",";

}
$seperator .= "\n";

echo $seperator;

//putting the heading into the csv file
fputs($fp,$seperator);


mysqli_data_seek($result,0);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value){

    if (strcmp($name,'summary') == 0){


            $value = str_replace( array( "\r" , "\n", "\r\n", "\n\r" ) ,'' , $value);
            $value = str_replace('</b><br>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<b>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<br>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<br />','',$value);
    }

    $seperator.= $comma. ''.str_replace('','""',$value);
    $comma=",";

    }
$seperator .= "\n";


//putting the heading into the csv file
fputs($fp,$seperator);


}

fclose($fp);



?>
```

Running the above script stores the .csv file in the folder uploads. What changes to do i need to make to enable browser download so that users can run the script and download the .csv file via the browser? thanks!

**EDIT:**
Furthermore what modifications would i have to make if wanted to disable saving to the folder and only enable user/browser downloads? thanks.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add tag [tag:homework].

Comment: @Christian: Despite not mentioning it i did try different methods of getting it to work but failed. On another note, this is a work project with a deadline. I needed to get what had to be done and then go figure out the why.

Comment: In my opinion, I'd reject work which I don't know how to carry out in the first place...

Comment: @Christian: Well in my opinion, i consider it a challenge but lets agree to disagree and leave it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: great! that seems to work. However it appears to add the table titles twice - any idea why? thanks.

Comment: strange, don't think that this has anything to do with the download. Are you sure that the original `$filename` is looking as it should?

Comment: well yeah considering the data is there.?Its just the title that gets added twice..

Comment: Muller: btw it doesn't have the extra title line in the .csv file in the uploads directory, only in the browser downloaded version.

Comment: Sorry, has to be something else. Try with another browser? This is the standard approach of download csv files that I have been using for years without problems, this issue has to be something else.

Comment: Check if you don't have any empty space before your `<?php` and after your `?>`.

Comment: @DavidMüller: Thanks. Just wondering..I'm putting my code just above the `fclose($fp);` does that seem about right? I've tried it in IE and Firefox.
@Ninsuo: yup no empty spaces.

Comment: Try putting it below `fclose`.

Comment: @DavidMüller: Sadly still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

surely the table titles appear twice because this line appears twice in the code in different places:

```
//putting the heading into the csv file
fputs($fp,$seperator);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think following two lines enough to force browser to auto download csv file

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="dishes.csv"');

where filename -- give name name csv file name